# Hive returns too many rows in create table as select

Tags: hadoop, duplicates, hive, create-table

*hive unwanted duplicates in simple query*

**our data:**

- table xx contains unique uuid1s
- results contain (in some cases) duplicate uuid1s
- we have 256 uuid1 shards

  create table xx as (
  uuid1shard char(2),
  uuid1 char(36)
  timestamp timestamp,
  uuid2shard char(2),
  uuid2 (char(36),
  col001 .. col190 int/bigint/char,
  payload varchar(100)
  )

**our findings:**

works ok:

```
select
row_number() over (partition by uuid2shard, uuid2 order by (timestamp, uuid2shard, uuid2))
,*
from (select * from xx where uuidshard2 < 192)
```

somehow works (count(*) > count(distinct uuid2):

```
select
row_number() over (partition by uuid2shard, uuid2 order by (timestamp, uuid2shard, uuid2))
,*
from (select * from xx where uuidshard2 < 192)
```

results (~800M) contain cca 8000 duplicate rows (completely same) when saved via create table

everything works ok, when just checked -

```
select count(*), count(distinct uuid2) from 
(
select
row_number() over (partition by uuid2shard, uuid2 order by (timestamp, uuid2shard, uuid2))
,*
from xx
)
```

works again: --just ignore remaining 190 columns

```
select
row_number() over (partition by uuid2shard, uuid2 order by (timestamp, uuid2shard, uuid2))
, partition by uuid1shard, uuid1, timestamp, uuid2shard, uuid2, smallpayload
from xx
```

**root cause** *pinned it* (where do all the dups come from?):

```
create table yy as --the CREATE, yes, the problem is probably in the create statement
select
row_number() over (partition by uuid2shard, uuid2 order by (timestamp, uuid2shard, uuid2))
,*
from xx
```

looks like it is 'size' issue, or there must be something to set to make it work

**our environment:**

small one ;)
16 nodes, 384 VCores etc...

Comment: Can you clarify more what you mean by duplicates?  Your table creation query as specified is going to create table `yy` with exactly the same number of rows that was in `xx`.  There isn't any aggregation going on here, if that's your intent.

Comment: created table has a bit more rows than the origina (~8k out of ~800M)

Comment: scarying, isn't it? ;) checked hundred times
And the duplicates are doubled (exactly the same) rows - there is not 1 row 8000 times, but there are 8000 rows twice in the created table.
my first guess was it is something in the data format, but it happens whether we use ORC or TEXT (for source and target)

Comment: faced the same issue. weird as hell